# How to get all buttons from a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the buttons in javascript from the div tag. I tried by using this code:-

```
function endBtn() {
    btns = document.getElementsByClassName("endbtn");
    hpBtns = btns[0].getElementsByTagName("button");

}
```

But this code is giving me this error: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
This is my HTML code

```
<div class="endbtn">
            <button id="hint">Hint</button>
            <button id="PA">Play again</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you have posted is working, maybe you have some other issue

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` is what you want:

```
const hpBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".endbtn button");
```

Live example:

```js
const hpBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".endbtn button");
console.log("There are", hpBtns.length, "buttons")
```

```html
<div class="endbtn">
  <button id="hint">Hint</button>
  <button id="PA">Play again</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, It works and it is not giving any error, but getting problem on addEventListener()

Comment: `addEventListener` didnt appear anywhere in your question?!

Comment: ohh sorry, I'm getting problem on addEventListener because hpBtns.length is giving me the output zero.